# JasperReports - subreports with tables - parameter passing

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm using JRBeanCollectionDataSource objects for data, and trying to figure out how to arrange the Java objects (and, I guess, the relevant settings in the JRXML).

Specifically, I've got a sub-report defined that works great standalone, which uses a Table. In order to populate the rows of the table, I pass in a datasource that's an array of data beans, passed as a parameter to the report.

However, when embedding that report as a sub-report within a master report, I'm not clear on how I'm supposed to pass in the corresponding data objects.  I can't seem to find any examples of this, though. If you know of any examples, that'd be great!

Otherwise, what I've got so far:

Each sub-report has a few parameters and 3 tables.

Data Bean (each one is basically a row of a table):

```
public class DataBean {
    public String c1_name;
    public String c2_name;
    public String c1_value;
    public String c2_value;

    public String getC1_name() {
        return c1_name;
    }
    public void setC1_name(String s) {
        this.c1_name = s;
    }
    public String getC2_name() {
        return c2_name;
    }
    public void setC2_name(String s) {
        this.c2_name = s;
    }
    public String getC1_value() {
        return c1_value;
    }
    public void setC1_value(String s) {
        this.c1_value = s;
    }
    public String getC2_value() {
        return c2_value;
    }
    public void setC2_value(String s) {
        this.c2_value = s;
    }
}
```

Master Bean (has datasets for all 3 tables and the 3 parameters needed for each sub-report):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MasterBean {
    private ArrayList<DataBean> t1; // Table 1
    private ArrayList<DataBean> t2a; // Table 2, column 1
    private ArrayList<DataBean> t2b; // Table 2, column 2
    private String disclaimer;
    private String event_detail;
    private String event_type;

    public ArrayList<DataBean> getT1() {
        return t1;
    }
    public void setT1(ArrayList<DataBean> beanlist) {
        this.t1 = beanlist;
    }

    public ArrayList<DataBean> getT2a() {
        return t2a;
    }
    public void setT2a(ArrayList<DataBean> beanlist) {
        this.t2a = beanlist;
    }

    public ArrayList<DataBean> getT2b() {
        return t2b;
    }
    public void setT2b(ArrayList<DataBean> beanlist) {
        this.t2b = beanlist;
    }

    public String getDisclaimer() {
        return disclaimer;
    }
    public void setDisclaimer(String s) {
        this.disclaimer = s;
    }

    public String getEvent_detail() {
        return event_detail;
    }
    public void setEvent_detail(String s) {
        this.event_detail = s;
    }

    public String getEvent_type() {
        return event_type;
    }
    public void setEvent_type(String s) {
        this.event_type = s;
    }
}
```

And to fill the report (the interesting bits), I was sort of winging it because I haven't found any documentation:

```
            ... (snip) ...
            DataBeanList DataBeanList = new DataBeanList();

            ArrayList<DataBean> t1_1 = DataBeanList.getDataBeanList(0);
            ArrayList<DataBean> t2a_1 = DataBeanList.getDataBeanList(1);
            ArrayList<DataBean> t2b_1 = DataBeanList.getDataBeanList(2);
            MasterBean sub1 = new MasterBean();
            sub1.setT1(t1_1);
            sub1.setT2a(t2a_1);
            sub1.setT2b(t2b_1);
            sub1.setDisclaimer("Disclaimer 1 goes here");
            sub1.setEvent_detail("Event Detail 1 goes here");
            sub1.setEvent_type("Event Type 1 goes here");

            ArrayList<DataBean> t1_2 = DataBeanList.getDataBeanList(0);
            ArrayList<DataBean> t2a_2 = DataBeanList.getDataBeanList(1);
            ArrayList<DataBean> t2b_2 = DataBeanList.getDataBeanList(2);
            MasterBean sub2 = new MasterBean();
            sub2.setT1(t1_2);
            sub2.setT2a(t2a_2);
            sub2.setT2b(t2b_2);
            sub2.setDisclaimer("Disclaimer 2 goes here");
            sub2.setEvent_detail("Event Detail 2 goes here");
            sub2.setEvent_type("Event Type 2 goes here");

            ArrayList<DataBean> t1_3 = DataBeanList.getDataBeanList(0);
            ArrayList<DataBean> t2a_3 = DataBeanList.getDataBeanList(1);
            ArrayList<DataBean> t2b_3 = DataBeanList.getDataBeanList(2);
            MasterBean sub3 = new MasterBean();
            sub3.setT1(t1_3);
            sub3.setT2a(t2a_3);
            sub3.setT2b(t2b_3);
            sub3.setDisclaimer("Disclaimer 3 goes here");
            sub3.setEvent_detail("Event Detail 3 goes here");
            sub3.setEvent_type("Event Type 3 goes here");

            ArrayList<MasterBean> masterList = new ArrayList<MasterBean>();
            masterList.add(sub1);
            masterList.add(sub2);
            masterList.add(sub3);

            JRBeanCollectionDataSource datasource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(masterList);

            Map params = new HashMap();

            params.put("report_type","Master Report Type");

            try {
```

/deaton/jasper/jasperreports-5.5.1/demo/samples/testme/reports/CASummary.jrxml");
                    JasperReport jasperSub = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("/home/deaton/jasper/jasperreports-5.5.1/demo/samples/testme/reports/CAEventDetails.jrxml");
                    params.put("subreportParameter",jasperSub);
params, tdatasource);
params, new JREmptyDataSource(2));
                    JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile("build/reports/CASummary.jasper", params, datasource);
                ... (snip) ...

For the sub-report, here's some of the interesting bits in the JRXML:

```
    ... (snip) ...
    <subDataset name="instrument_details" uuid="6d672249-f7b2-44ca-9f8a-6cb4995fdfab">
            <field name="c1_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
            <field name="c1_value" class="java.lang.String"/>
            <field name="c2_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
            <field name="c2_value" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="event_information" uuid="f2f954af-98c1-4f2b-9c57-e666d309fdce">
            <field name="c1_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
            <field name="c1_value" class="java.lang.String"/>
            <field name="c2_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
            <field name="c2_value" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="disclaimer" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="event_detail" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="event_type" class="java.lang.String"/>

    <parameter name="DS1" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <parameter name="DS2" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <parameter name="DS3" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>

    <field name="event_comments" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="event_description" class="java.lang.String"/>

    ... (skip down) ...

                    <componentElement>
                            <reportElement key="table" style="table" x="0" y="20" width="572" height="20" uuid="a3e03a5d-48cd-4bf4-82f4-df7de7958a75"/>
                            <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                                    <datasetRun subDataset="instrument_details" uuid="1e25358d-f600-4ea3-80b3-f15d4438992c">
                                            <datasetParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                                                    <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{DS1}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                                            </datasetParameter>
                                    </datasetRun>
                                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="f4c26fd2-95ae-49a4-8b6f-8fbe6f47f810">
                                            <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                                                    <textField>
                                                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="578b42c1-3065-419a-8758-4e1b4946ca04"/>
                                                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{c1_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                                    </textField>
                                            </jr:detailCell>
                                    </jr:column>
                                    <jr:column width="186" uuid="ceb83fa5-ed21-4cca-b374-aae224688297">
                                            <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                                                    <textField>
                                                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="186" height="20" uuid="d5cdb3c8-af89-4af7-bd94-ee6fda45f327"/>
                                                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{c1_value}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                                    </textField>
                                            </jr:detailCell>
                                    </jr:column>
                                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="ca9810a7-6684-49e2-b673-ed84278a5d20">
                                            <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                                                    <textField>
                                                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="e6765684-2042-47e7-858d-b2b0d9ae8eaf"/>
                                                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{c2_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                                    </textField>
                                            </jr:detailCell>
                                    </jr:column>
                                    <jr:column width="186" uuid="c99af79c-5373-41c4-a05a-4538da4504df">
                                            <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                                                    <textField>
                                                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="186" height="20" uuid="e4079374-640c-4a79-b315-a1f33079bfd3"/>
                                                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{c2_value}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                                    </textField>
                                            </jr:detailCell>
                                    </jr:column>
                            </jr:table>
                    </componentElement>
    ... (above repeated for other tables) ...
```

And finally, the part where I suspect I'm WAY off, the master report, where I'm clueless:

```
    ... (snip) ...
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["/home/deaton/jasper/jasperreports-5.5.1/demo/samples/testme/build/reports/"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="report_type" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="master_source" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <parameter name="subreportParameter" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"/>

    <field name="disclaimer" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="event_detail" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="event_type" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="t1" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <field name="t2a" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <field name="t2b" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>

    ... (skip a bit) ...

    <detail>
            <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
                    <subreport>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="572" height="125" uuid="aba34d2d-04ee-4ff7-803b-14424c825b3f"/>
                            <subreportParameter name="disclaimer">
                                    <subreportParameterExpression>
                                            <![CDATA[$F{disclaimer}]]>
                                    </subreportParameterExpression>
                            </subreportParameter>

                            <subreportParameter name="event_detail">
                                    <subreportParameterExpression>
                                            <![CDATA[$F{event_detail}]]>
                                    </subreportParameterExpression>
                            </subreportParameter>

                            <subreportParameter name="event_type">
                                    <subreportParameterExpression>
                                            <![CDATA[$F{event_type}]]>
                                    </subreportParameterExpression>
                            </subreportParameter>

                            <subreportParameter name="DS1">
                                    <subreportParameterExpression>
                                            <![CDATA[$F{t1}]]>
                                    </subreportParameterExpression>
                            </subreportParameter>

                            <subreportParameter name="DS2">
                                    <subreportParameterExpression>
                                            <![CDATA[$F{t2a}]]>
                                    </subreportParameterExpression>
                            </subreportParameter>

                            <subreportParameter name="DS3">
                                    <subreportParameterExpression>
                                            <![CDATA[$F{t2b}]]>
                                    </subreportParameterExpression>
                            </subreportParameter>

                            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "CAEventDetails.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                    </subreport>
            </band>
    </detail>
    ... (snip) ...
```

When I run this, it compiles, fills the report, but then... nothing. No data gets into my report. I can't even see any of the static elements of my subreport inside the master report (tried with empty datasets with multiples, but still zilch).

So... I suspect I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, but I can't seem to figure out how to pass parameters appropriately to the sub-report based on the main datasource, or as a sub-record of a parameter. I've tried a bunch of combinations, but everything seems to either fail to compile, or gives me no data.

Comment: So, update, I also tried making my masterList be the datasource for the report, and then passing in parameters as $F{t1}, $F{disclaimer}, etc., but to no avail. Although it compiles, it doesn't even seem to print any portion of the subreport at all...

Comment: sure about the filenames ?? I found "CA" before the names..??

Comment: Sorry, I modified the filenames a bit before posting, since some of them are lengthy-- I don't ... think the filenames are an issue (although they were at one point, where the assumed directory path was different).

As of now, I don't get any compilation errors (passing in the parameters to the subreport from fields), but... I don't get any content either. I get the header and summary for the master report, but zilch for the subreport data.

I guess I should update to reflect what I'm doing now-- but mostly I'm hoping someone can point me in the direction of how these are usually done.

Comment: Updated the code snippits in the question so they're more accurate (not edited), but still no real progress. Still yields no data.